# How to convert a 'double' with scientific notation to a 'String' that shows it in numbers instead of the notation in Java?

Tags: java, string, printing, double

For example if-
double d = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
String str += d;
Here, the 'String str' will be a scientific notation value but I want it to be equal to the number value instead, not the scientific notation form.
Thank you!
P.S- I cannot import any library like BigDecimal etc.

Comment: double has limited precision, perhaps you want BigDecimal or BigInteger instead.

Comment: `String.format("%.0f", d)` does what you seem to want.

Comment: (but I feel this may be an "XY problem". What are you actually trying to do?)

Comment: (Strictly speaking, you can use `BigDecimal` without importing it. )

Comment: Thank you guys, it works! I found out that the BigInteger/BigDecimal class is not blacklisted, sorry about that. It was blacklisted in one of the other questions so I assumed the same.